# Chromium not loading google related sites, youtube ubuntu ask etc

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, chromium, youtube, google

noob here having issues with google, youtube, etc not loading running 12.04 LTS.  I uninstalled and reinstalled chromium various times.  I'd hate to reinstall 12.04 as i have had issues with various programs and now everything was working fine over the last couple of months.

Comment: Chromium in Ubuntu 12.04 is outdated. You can use Firefox instead.

Comment: I'd like to stick to chromium as all of my links are synced to my gmail

Comment: Then upgrade your system to 14.04.

Comment: yup, totally related.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium browser is not updated for Ubuntu 12.04.

It is still version `37.0.2062.120` while the current version is `48.0.2564.82`.

Some web sites may require newer version of a browser due to security issues, etc.

You can use Firefox in 12.04, or you need to upgrade to 14.04.